# How to send email to all team members of project in openerp v7?

Tags: email, odoo

I want to send an email to all the team members of 'project' when it is created. Any idea how to achieve this in openerp v7?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Lots of people here will be more than willing to help you when you get stuck with something specific, but we will not do your work for you. If you want a good answer, you'll need to demonstrate that you've put some effort into finding one yourself. Please read [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) for pointers.